# Corrections after paper published online

Tags: online-publication

I recently found that in my recent paper published online before print (online first), I missed two important references and an acknowledgement of someone who helped me. What is the best way forward? Anyone had any experience dealing with SAGE? I appreciate any advice on this...

Comment: Have you tried writing the editor of the journal? In my experience this is something they are happy to do.

Comment: In my experience some journals do not allow changes to a paper which has been published online already. In this case the editors might offer to publish an erratum notice.

Comment: thanks Nabla and user93559. If I email the editor, how soon will they implement the changes?

Comment: It depends significantly on journal. Some journals actually have separate proofs for the online-first/print editions (don't ask me why, but I have had the experience of having to do effectively two rounds of galley proofing because of that). Some journals the online-first are not copy-edited (just taking your submission and framing it in the journal style and that's it). Some journals the online-first are fully proofed and your manuscript is basically just sitting in a queue waiting to be printed. As you can imagine the response would be significantly different for all.

Comment: Thanks Willie for your comments. I have contacted the copy editor and they are happy to take the changes but they will not do it until the article is assigned to an issue. This journal has a long queue .. it might take one or two year... So they have to ask the editor for approval to have it assigned to the latest issue. That is a real pain as I do not really want my articles  on line without rights reference...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make corrections to a published paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/520/how-do-you-make-corrections-to-a-published-paper)